# BitmapFactory.decodeStream returns null without exception

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I try to load a remote image from a server and thanks to a lot of code examples on stackoverflow I have a solution which works in 2 out of 3 images. I don't really know what the problem is with the third picture and sometimes when letting the code run in the debugger the picture is loading. Also if I load the problem picture first the other two pictures are sometimes not loaded.

Here is the code:

```
public static Drawable getPictureFromURL(Context ctx, String url, final int REQUIRED_SIZE) throws NullPointerException {
    //Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    int scale = 1;
    if (o.outWidth > REQUIRED_SIZE) {
        scale = (int) Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(REQUIRED_SIZE / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
    }
    Log.i(Prototype.TAG, "scale: "+scale); 

    //Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    Bitmap bmp;
    try {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) Tools.fetch(url), null, o2);
        if(bmp!=null)
            return new BitmapDrawable(ctx.getResources(), bmp);
        else
            return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(Prototype.TAG, "Exception while decoding stream", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

During debugging I found out that o.outWidth is -1 which indicates an error, but no Exception is thrown, so I can't really tell what went wrong. The InputStream always returned a valid value, and I know that the picture exists on the server.

Best wishes,
Daniel

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/droid-fu-part-2-webimageview-and-webgalleryadapter/#comment-747) and updated the fetch method to:

```
private static InputStream fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
    HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(address) );
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
    InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
    return instream;
}
```

Comment: +1, but it seems now that the images are being downloaded in sequence instead of in parallel (I am dl-ing each image on a separate AsyncTask). At least it works..