# Bitmap gets null when getting facebook profile picture

Tags: android, facebook, bitmap

I'm trying to get my facebook profile picture by

```
URL fb_pic = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+(facebookuserID)+"/picture?style=small" );
```

Ihave successfully got the image url.But when i try to convert the url into Bitmap i'm not getting response,

```
Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fb_pic.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Please give me a solution...!!!

Comment: This looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011967/cannot-load-image-from-a-url-using-bitmapfactory-decodestream

Answer (score 2):

This code is working for me

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(linkUrl) ); 
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest); 
HttpEntity entrty = response.getEntity(); 
BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity); 
bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufHttpEntity.getContent());

httpRequest.abort();
```