# How to get image from AppEngine Server into Android activity

Tags: android, google-app-engine, httpclient

I'm trying to fetch an image from the AppEngine server in development mode, using this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414839/bitmapfactory-decodestream-returns-null-without-exception):

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(url) );
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse resp = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);
```

When executing the 3rd line (httpclient.execute(..)) I get the error:

> W/System.err(508): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException:
>   Connection to http://0.0.0.0:8888 refused

This URL http://0.0.0.0:8888 is correct I believe, because in this App Engine connected Android project, I'm able to fetch images with this address on the browser client side of the project. (Again, I'm in local development mode)

Why is this connection being refused?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`http://0.0.0.0:8888` is certainly not correct. You need to use the IP address of the computer where the App engine development server is running. If you are on a local network that would be something like 192.168.x.xxx. Type `ipconfig` on Windows or `/sbin/ifconfig` on Linux in a a terminal to find out the address of your development machine. Then use that to access it from Android.

Comment: If I put http://0.0.0.0:8888/... directly into my browser, it displays the image that I'm trying to get in the android app.  Also, this same address is used on the GWT client side of the app for the same purpose of fetching an image and it works there also, so the address is in some ways correct at least. Not sure why it doesn't work on the Android side yet.

Comment: However, when I use 192.168.... in the Android side of the app, it is in fact able to fetch the image.  Any ideas why it works on GWT side but not the Android side?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not an address you can connect from another machine, it's similar to the `127.0.0.1` (localhost, loopback) address. It means 'all addresses on the _local_ machine'. That is why it works on your desktop. However, if you want to connect from another machine, in this case your Android device, you need to use a real interface address. Use the commands above to find out what yours is.

Comment: Yes, thanks, when I use the real address, it works on the Android emulator.