# BitmapFactory.decodeStream not working

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I'm having a bit of a problem with decodeStream returning null. It seems to be a fairly common problem around, but it's usually pinned down to one of two problems:

- An OutOfMemory exception thrown by attempting to load a large bitmap in it's entirety.
- Attempting to use the same input stream twice.

However, I'm not doing either. The code to run it is simply

```
stream = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
stream.close();
```

with the URL set to [here](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/bmp/bmp_24.bmp). image is null after this code is complete. This issue's been driving me completely insane - it works fine on PNGs but seems to fall apart under every BMP I can give it, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, the answer was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414839/bitmapfactory-decodestream-returns-null-without-exception?rq=1), using an InputStream returned by a BufferedHTTPEntity. While it seems needlessly complex, I can only assume that simply getting a stream from the URL object directly doesn't return a stream of the appropriate type, and so it wasn't reading out all the data properly.

Cross-posting the code in case the question is erased:

```
private static InputStream fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
    HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(address) );
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
    InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
    return instream;
}
```