# Why is BitmapFactory.decodeStream returning null?

Tags: android, json, bitmap, bitmapfactory

Basically I am parsing some JSON that has an image with it and trying to load it into a ImageView. However **mBitmap** is returning null. I have no idea why and further research has not helped..

Here is an example url I am working with:

```
http://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/ivBAJzLMJEkEy9jgTy3z4n-mO7gIGt5mQFU1Al5kJ-I.jpg
```

Here is all relevant code:

```
 public static Bitmap LoadImageFromUrl(String url){
   try {
      mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());
       return mBitmap;
    }catch (Exception e){
       Log.d(TAG,"Error getting image");
       return null;
   }
}
```

Here is where the method is called:

```
mListingModel.setmImageView(LoadImageFromUrl(data.getString(JSON_THUMBNAIL)));
```

Here is where I set the ImageView:

```
    if(mItem.getmImageView() != null) {
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(mItem.getmImageView());
    }
```

**Note: I am calling the method in an AsyncTask so that is not the problem.**

Comment: What kind of permissions does your app have? Also: include your logcat, just in case there's something in there...

Comment: I would recommend using any of the dozens of libraries for image loading, rather than trying to use `getContent()` on `URL`. You are more likely to get more logging information that can help you isolate your problems, and they usually can handle asynchronously populating an `ImageView`. Consider [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), for example.

Comment: @DigCamara I already have the Internet Permission included in my manifest as it is loading other data from the website. I'll try to include my logcat info when I get home.

Comment: @CommonsWare I appreciate the help. Do you think I should have another thread going? I already have an AsyncTask going that populates my Listviews etc. But I will look into Picasso.

Comment: Why this question has +2? CHECK LOGCAT'S LOG. I'm pretty sure that you have " Error getting image" there... edit +3...  Are you have some sockpupet accounts?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question at the end and  BitMap is null and I do get the log that says "Error getting image", I also had a log that gave me the value of mBitMap but I took it out. Just so you understand my questions better.

Comment: Post your complete codes and also stack trace!

Comment: Did you try this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096962/bitmapfactory-decodestream-not-working ?

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc for [Bitmap.decodeStream()](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) states that:

> If the input stream is null, or cannot be used to decode a bitmap, the
>   function returns null

You're passing it the results of [URL.getContent()](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/net/URL.html#getContent%28%29), which states in its javadoc:

> By default this returns an InputStream, or null if the content type of
>   the response is unknown.

So maybe you should check to see if getContent() returns null before passing it on to the decoder.

Answer (score 1):

i had in the past stupid problems like having my stream reached the end before i decoded it, so ensure to set it's position to 0 before decoding the stream

eg.

```
stream.Position = 0;
var bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if this works for you:

```
InputStream in = new java.net.URL(downloadURL).openStream();
Bitmap avatarBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
in.close();
```

Also a reminder to add this in your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I tried to find decode fail reason.. but I couldn't find.
I just confirmed that `InputStream` and `BufferedInputStream` are not null.

After **restarting my AVD**.. the problem was resolved even though I didn't change any code.

Comment: The same error is happening again.. but to restart my AVD is.. not working now..