# BitmapFactory .decodeStream some time return null

Tags: java, android

I have inputStream Object when i try to convert in bitmap it works but for some images it will return me null still, image is present.

```
InputStream responseInputStream = apiResponseModel
                .getResponseInputStream();
if (responseInputStream != null) {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(responseInputStream);
    imgProductProfile.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Comment: try using `Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();`    `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;` `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(responseInputStream, null, options);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [BitmapFactory.decodeStream returns null without exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414839/bitmapfactory-decodestream-returns-null-without-exception)

Comment: don't forget to `close()` your `responseInputStream `

Answer (score 0):

The image you are trying to decode may not be supported for decoding. Android supports only few image types for decoding. The supported format is listed here 
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html. Try converting your image to other format like PNG , JPG and try decoding

Comment: this issue is device specific.